# Vertical align entire row in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically center a Bootstrap 3 row. I've got no other content on the site other than the HTML you see here. So far it hasn't really worked.

I also tried some codes that I found on the internet, but none of them seem to work. As you can see, I tried to wrap everything after the container in a separate `div` so the row would center inside it. It doesn't work, sadly.

```
<?php include_once ("header.php") ?>

<div id="bg"></div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Navigation area -->
  <?php include_once ("navigation.php");?>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical">
    <div id="fade" class="about-wrapper animated fadeInLeft">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 nova">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="../covers/nova-about.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 opa">
          <div class="title">
            <h3>Leo</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="title">
            <h3>Age 7</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="title">
            <h3>Character</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="describ">
            <p>
              Leo is calm, playful and a tiny guard dog. He is very social and loves to play with other dogs.
              <br> He gets a little greedy when you caress him but he can also like it to relax alone on the couch. Overall a Dream dog to have and we are lucky he is ours.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="title">
            <h3>Introduction to the Family</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="describ">
            <p>
              Leo was our first dog we had. We nearly took a different one but as she was reserved, he "puppy-eyed" his way into Roannes heart.
              <br> His young appearence made him even more sympathetic and he enjoyed it instantly with his new Family.
              <br>
              <br><strong>Fun fact:</strong> I randomly met the real owner in the bus and he told me leo was only sent to SPA because he cant be alone in the house and was making too much noise. Well, lucky us!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include_once ("footer.php") ?>
```

The CSS:

```
.vertical {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
 }
```

To clear things up, I want the row itself to be centered so that I don't have to play around with `top: 25vh` as I think it might be too inconsistent.

Comment: Are you trying to vertical align `div.vertical` or `div.row`?

Comment: just use `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` for `.row` if clearly understood what you trying to achieve

Comment: im trying to achieve a vertical centered row. as in the row itself. sec imma try. Sadly your flex solution doesnt work. tried  `.vertical` `.row` `.container`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/uz7dL7cq/

Comment: vertical centering it, not horizontal. like `margin-top: 50%` & `margin-bottom: 50%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following CSS seems to be giving the desired result:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Check out the fiddle that I made for this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2678jhbh/2/

Comment: this worked, i mark it as accepted due to  the fact that putting it on the row itself solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.vertical {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical">
    <div id="fade" class="about-wrapper animated fadeInLeft">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 nova">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="../covers/nova-about.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 opa">

          <div class="title">
            <h3>Leo</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="title">
            <h3>Age 7</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="title">
            <h3>Character</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="describ">
            <p>
              Leo is calm, playful and a tiny guard dog. He is very social and loves to play with other dogs.
              <br> He gets a little greedy when you caress him but he can also like it to relax alone on the couch. Overall a Dream dog to have and we are lucky he is ours.
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="title">
            <h3>Introduction to the Family</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="describ">
            <p>
              Leo was our first dog we had. We nearly took a different one but as she was reserved, he "puppy-eyed" his way into Roannes heart.
              <br> His young appearence made him even more sympathetic and he enjoyed it instantly with his new Family.
              <br>
              <br><strong>Fun fact:</strong> I randomly met the real owner in the bus and he told me leo was only sent to SPA because he cant be alone in the house and was making too much noise. Well, lucky us!
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.vertical {
  min-height: 100vh; // optionally use calc to offset navigation
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: flex doesnt help me at all with VERTICAL alignment bootstraps row & col-xs-6 does the HORIZONTAL centering work.

Comment: @limitless check the snippet

Comment: ok well u were right except that putting it on the vertical div somehow didnt do anything for me. the other post who put it on row made this actually work. i am not sure why but for the sake of people getting the right answer  i have to accept the other ones answer. sorry

Answer (score 0):

To center the div with the class `row`, remove the `.vertical` css and try:

```
.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

Setting `top` and `left` to 50% will bring the top left corner of the div to the middle of the parent. Then using negative margins we can bring the div over to the left and up a bit to finish centering it correctly.

Comment: seems logical but the .row has its own properties and the mix just ends up messing it up completely. especially with the content.

Comment: @Limitless Sorry I thought it was supposed to be for `.row`. It should work if you specify `.vertical` instead

Comment: that seems better. 2 problems. 1. its not 100% middled (unless taking a ruler is not a valid option) and 2. i like bootstraps width & height of the collums, but if i remove ur H & W it goes horribly wrong. any ideas on how to keep BS's collum size the same but middling it out?

Comment: i mean. adding ´top: 25vh;´ nearly perfects it. but im pretty sure its inconsistent across screen sizes and devices.